# get value of input tag from td tag generated by for loop

Tags: jquery

i want to get the current price of the element whose qunatity has been changed.
i am just able to change the price of the 1st elements but not the others
please help me in getting the quantity of the element selected from the drop down menu of the quantity .

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> //quantity retrival
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.quantityx').change(function(){
        alert("message");

        var tot =$('#pricexx').val()* this.value;
         alert(this.parent.find('input[name=pricexx]').val());

         });

    });
    </script>

    <table id="mytable">

                    <%
                        int i = 0;
                        while (it.hasNext()) {
                            i++;
                            Product_List PL = (Product_List) it.next();

                            list.add("" + PL.getProduct_id());
                            String order = list.toString();
                            session.setAttribute("orders", order);
                    %><tr class="row">



                        <td class="delete">
                            <div class="centererer">
                                <form action="PDelete" method="get">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="p_id" value="<%=PL.getProduct_id()%>"
                                        id="Product_id" /> <input type="submit" class="close">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="image"><img src="<%=PL.getImage()%>" width="86"
                            height="86" /></td>
                        <td class="name"><%=PL.getBrand()%> <%=PL.getDetail()%></td>
                        <td class="size"><%=PL.getCloth_size()%></td>

                        <td class="price">&#8377;<input name="pricexx" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<%=PL.getPrice()%>"></td>
                        <td class="quauntity">
                        <select class="quantityx">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>


                            </td>
                        <%!int totalprice, netprice = 0,quant=1;%>
                        <%
                            totalprice = quant * PL.getPrice();
                        %>
                        <%
                            netprice = totalprice + netprice;
                        %>

                        <td class="price">&#8377;<input id="tp" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<%=totalprice%>"></td>

                    </tr>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                </table>
                <!--         -->
                <input type="hidden" value="<%=list.toString()%>" name="array" /> <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <td  class="size"></td> -->
                        <td class="total">TOTAL <span class="pricex">&#8377;<%=netprice%></span></td>


                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is not correct for getting current `input[name=pricexx]`. You should do this way

```
var input = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[name=pricexx]');
var tot = input.val() * this.value;
```